# How do I know the IDs of the multiple links that are involved in the shortest distance between any two points in a Network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

[image]

I don't just want to find the shortest distance between any points in the Network Dataset but find which links (the IDs) are involved in the shortest path.

At the end I want a table that includes the origin, destination, and the links involved in the shortest distance between origin and destination. I have around 80,000 rows in the Origin-Destination Table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specifically mention *Network Dataset* in your question so I am assuming you are not using a geometric network.  In a geometric network the results of a trace can be shown as a graphic or a selection of the edges, it's simply an option you turn on/off.

So assuming you are using a *Network Dataset* then to my knowledge there is no equivalent option to turn on/off. You can do the following to identify the individual edges:

- Create your route layer
- Add 2 flags and solve the route
- Use the select by location to use the route you just created to select the edges.

[image: Screen shot]

- The trick is the spatial method (have their centroid in source layer) which you use. Simply using intersect will select roads at junctions which you want to avoid.
- You can then interrogate or export the selection.

Comment: But, my main objective is not just to get one route, but multiple routes at the same time. The final table of shortest route not just include the route length but the ID's of the Links on the Shortest Path.

Comment: You need to be reading the help file about model builder, it can all be done using that.